# Does there exist an English translation of Distler's paper on solving polynomials by radicals?

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory

The [Radiroot](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/radiroot/doc/manual.pdf) package for GAP by Andreas Distler solves by radicals polynomials with solvable Galois group. The package uses the algorithm described in Distler's paper "[Ein Algorithmus zum Lösen einer Polynomgleichung durch Radikal](http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/ag_algebra/software/distler/Diplom.pdf)". As you would guess from the title, the paper is in German, which I cannot read. Is there an English (or Russian) translation of this paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked around, but can't seem to find a translated version of the paper, be it English or Russian.  I did Google it. As a last resort, you can try Google's "translate" option: it rendered a decent translation, though formatting suffers.

Perhaps your best bet would be to contact [Andrew Distler](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/radiroot.html) directly?

Comment: @WillHunting, thanks for the update to the post, and clearing "dead" links!